# How to check if an ActiveRecord table entry is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I am not sure if the title of this question uses proper jargon, but hopefully this description will help. If you need more information, please let me know.

I am taking Chinese text from a form and splitting it into a 2d array of sentences and words. I then want to define all the words using dictionary entries in my database. Some of the words aren't in the database, so I want to check for that. What I am trying isn't working.

Here is my current code:

```
<% @lesson.parsed_content.each_with_index do |sentence, si| %> #iterate 1st dimension
  <% sentence.each_with_index do |word,wi| %> #iterate 2nd dimension
    <% sentence = sentence.to_s %>
    <div class="word blt" id="<%= wi %>">
    <div class="definition blt">
        <% definition = DictionaryEntry.where(:simplified => word) %> #search by simplified chinese
        <% definition.find_each do |w| %>
        <% if w.definition == nil %> # PROBLEM: this never returns true.
            <%= word %>
            <% else %>
        <%= w.definition %>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class='chinese blt'> <%= word %></div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How can I change `<% if w.definition == nil %>` to return true if there is no definition in my database?

Comment: Although this does not pertain to your question, beware of sql injection if you haven't already implemented measures. For more info, go here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

Comment: What is this line for? `<% sentence = sentence.to_s %>` Maybe it should go above `<% sentence.each_with_index do |word,wi| %> #iterate 2nd dimension`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark but first I would switch your code around when you are converting the variable sentence to a string and looping through it. (unless you have a reason for it being that way)

```
<% sentence = sentence.to_s %>
<% sentence.each_with_index do |word,wi| %> #iterate 2nd dimension
```

Second, depending on how your data was put inside the database it might be an empty string instead of nil. So I would change the condition from

```
<% if w.definition == nil %> # PROBLEM: this never returns true.
```

to

```
<% if w.definition.blank? %> # Checks to see if definition is blank
```

Blank will check if its false, empty, or a whitespace string.

Finally, indentation is helpful especially when running loops and conditionals. It's easier on the eyes and helps you understand what's going on.

```
<% @lesson.parsed_content.each_with_index do |sentence, si| %> 
  <% sentence = sentence.to_s %>
  <% sentence.each_with_index do |word,wi| %> 
    <div class="word blt" id="<%= wi %>">
      <div class="definition blt">
      <% definition = DictionaryEntry.where(:simplified => word) %> 
      <% if definition.empty? %>
        <% word %>
      <% else %>  
        <% definition.find_each do |w| %>
          <%= w.definition %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class='chinese blt'> <%= word %></div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Let me know the results.

Comment: Thanks. I tried ```<% if w.definition.blank? %>``` but it still never returned ```true```. Any other ideas? (I don't think the ```<% sentence = sentence.to_s %>``` is relevant. I removed it and the code produces the same results.

Comment: What does Rails Console return to you when you run the query?

Comment: I know how to run Rails Console, but I am not sure how I would run the query with it. Please have mercy on a noob. At least a hint?

Comment: It's fine. What you would do is go to your Console, then run `DictionaryEntry.where(:simplified => somewordhere)` where `somewordhere` represents a word that does not have a simplified translation. That way you can see what's actually in the database. From there we can figure out why its never returning true. But this brings up another question although it may be mute. Are there multiple definitions for a word?

Comment: I ran ```DictionaryEntry.where(:simplified => 'somewordhere')``` in the console  and it returned ```[]```. Then I tried ```<% if w.definition == [] %>``` and ```<% if w.definition == '[]' %>``` and they both never returned ```true```. Maybe I am missing something here. What does ```[]``` indicate? (p.s. There are multiple definitions for a word, but they are all just one long string.)

Comment: It means that what you're returned with is an empty array or in other words it found no results. Give me a second.

Comment: My answer is updated. I wasn't able to thoroughly look it over so if it doesn't work post the results. I'm determined to figure out this problem.

Comment: Running ```DictionaryEntry.where(:simplified => 'somewordhere').empty?``` in the console returns `true`, but for some reason the if statement doesn't work.

Comment: Never-mind. I didn't notice that you changed more than one line. It is working now! Yay!

Comment: Awesome. Glad it worked for you. As a suggestion go back and check out some more of the Ruby on Rails Guides and APIDock for Ruby. Mastering loops and arrays will prevent errors from this happening again.